# Autocorrect/complete extention for React Styled Components VScode

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, vscode-extensions

I'm not getting autocomplete or suggestions on my React styled components. Autocomplete works well otherwise except when I start writing the css in ``.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to extention manager and search "styled-component", i am using this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components